# iOS) How to set image's size and coordinate as the same as android

Tags: android, ios, image, png, psd

I'm developing ios app for a service that already has android application.

I have psd files and png files corresponding android one.

But I don't know how to set image's size and coordinate as the same as android....

Is there a way to follow android's ratio constructively?

I'm just setting imageview by eye measurement...
By eye measurement, I calculated ratio, size(width,height) and coordinate...

I want to make images set as the same as the android's one.
I'm just using 'aspect to fit', that makes this problem less heavy but not perfect

Comment: If the images are placed on pixel coordinates, then the original position can be expressed *relatively* as `x/screen_width` and `y_screen_height`. That will lead to a fractional position 0..1. Multiply by the iOS device screen size to get the exact *relative* placement again. (You also need to scale the image width and height by the same method. What if the aspect ratio of the screens are different?)

Answer (score 0):

Calculating everything manually will be horrible when you want to support multiple devices of different screen size. Use constraints if you want to scale the UIImageView to a certain ratio of another view.

Please refer to the auto layout guide at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Link is forbidden, is it just for me?

Comment: The links works for me. It's just an official reference for AutoLayout. Or you can just google for the term "AutoLayout", it should be the first one in the result list.